# Como colocar o pluggin LucidScroll a funcionar em apenas numa div

Tags: javascript, jquery

Eu estou usando um pluggin chamado LucidScroll que faz com que o scroll da pagina tenha uma animação mais suave durante o scroll, mas eu só queria que ela funciona-se em apenas uma div.

A pagina do pluggin é esta: http://ataredo.com/morphology/lucidscroll/

O meu codigo:

```js
var frameNumber = 0, // start video at frame 0
  // lower numbers = faster playback
  playbackConst = 500,
  // get page height from video duration
  setHeight = document.getElementById("set-height"),
  // select video element         
  vid = document.getElementById('myVideo');
// var vid = $('#v0')[0]; // jquery option

// dynamically set the page height according to video length
vid.addEventListener('loadedmetadata', function() {
  setHeight.style.height = Math.floor(vid.duration) * playbackConst + "px";
});


// Use requestAnimationFrame for smooth playback
function scrollPlay() {
  var frameNumber = window.pageYOffset / playbackConst;
  vid.currentTime = frameNumber;
  window.requestAnimationFrame(scrollPlay);
}

window.requestAnimationFrame(scrollPlay);

$(window).on('load', function() {

  /* $(this).impulse(); */

  $("set-height").hover(function() {
    var item = $('.boxes');

    $(this).impulse({
      range: item.height(),
      effect: 'swing',
      delay: true,
    });
  }, function() {
    $(this).impulse({
      range: 500,
      delay: false,
    });
  })
});



/*
 * LucidScroll
 * 
 * Created by Shikkediel (c) 2013-2019 ataredo.com
 * 
 * Version 3.4.3
 *
 * Requires jQuery 1.8.0+
 * Includes easing equations
 *
 */

(function($, nib) {

  $.fn.impulse = function(options) {

    var set = $.extend({}, $.fn.impulse.default, options),
      gate = $(nib),
      vessel = this,
      object = $(set.target),
      area = {},
      edge = [],
      fad = {},
      entity, brink = [],
      outset = [],
      quit = [],
      morph,
      way, speed, destined = [],
      pour = 'requestAnimationFrame',
      use = $.extend({
        novel: pour in nib,
        turned: 0
      }, set);

    elementAnalysis();

    vessel.each(function(hit) {

      use = $.extend({}, use);

      $(this).data('impulse', use).on('wheel.excite', function(act, info) {

        if (!use.keen && !act.mien) return;

        if (act.mien) {
          fad = $.extend({}, use, info);
          use.annul = fad.delay == true;
          var loom = act.mien;
          fad.fluid = false;
        } else {
          if (use.annul) return;
          fad = use;
          loom = act.originalEvent.deltaY;
        }

        loom = loom / Math.abs(loom);

        if (use.crux) {
          entity = $(this);
          brink[0] = edge[hit];
        } else {
          entity = object;
          brink = edge;
        }

        $.each({
          range: 'orbit',
          tempo: 'pace'
        }, function(slot, mate) {
          if (typeof fad[slot] === 'function') fad[mate] = fad[slot]();
          else fad[mate] = fad[slot];
        });

        if (loom != use.zeal || act.mien) use.turned = 1;
        else use.turned = Math.min(use.curb, use.turned + 1);

        if (!fad.delay && fad.fluid && use.turned == 1) morph = 'curve';
        else morph = fad.effect;

        way = loom * fad.orbit * Math.pow(use.leap, use.turned - 1);
        speed = fad.pace * Math.pow(use.sloth, use.turned - 1) || 1;
        use.zeal = loom;

        entity.each(function(part) {
          outset[part] = $(this).scrollTop();
          destined[part] = outset[part] + way;
          quit[part] = onFringe(this, part, outset[part]);
        });

        use.waive = ceaseOperation();

        if (!way) speed = 1;
        if (use.novel) {
          if (use.motion) {
            cancelAnimationFrame(use.motion);
            use.initial = use.present;
          } else use.initial = Date.now();
          use.motion = nib[pour](streamCore);
        } else inciteSource();
      });

      this.addEventListener('wheel', function(tick) {

        if (!use.keen) return;
        if (use.annul) return denyRise(tick);
        else if (fad.delay == true && !use.waive) use.annul = true;
        if (!(use.waive && use.occur)) denyRise(tick);

      }, hasQuiet() ? {
        passive: false
      } : false);
    });

    $.easing['curve'] = $.easing['easeInOutSine'];

    gate.resize(function() {
      clearTimeout(use.bound);
      use.bound = setTimeout(detectOverflow, 100);
    });

    return this;

    function streamCore() {
      use.present = Date.now();
      var advance = Math.min(use.present - use.initial, speed) / speed,
        increase = $.easing[morph](advance);
      entity.each(function(key) {
        if (!quit[key]) {
          $(this).scrollTop(outset[key] + increase * way);
          checkLimits(this, key, advance);
        }
      });
      if (advance < 1 && !use.waive) use.motion = nib[pour](streamCore);
      else hindStage();
    }

    function inciteSource() {
      entity.each(function(beat) {
        if (!quit[beat]) {
          $(this).stop().animate({
            scrollTop: destined[beat]
          }, {
            duration: speed,
            easing: morph,
            progress: function(current, sequence) {
              checkLimits(this, beat, sequence);
            },
            complete: hindStage
          });
        }
      });
    }

    function checkLimits(essence, rank, factor) {
      if (100 * factor >= fad.reset) use.turned = 0;
      if (onFringe(essence, rank)) {
        quit[rank] = true;
        if (!use.novel) $(essence).stop(true, true);
        use.waive = ceaseOperation();
      }
    }

    function onFringe(matter, cue, genesis) {
      var put = Math.round(genesis || $(matter).scrollTop()),
        above = destined[cue] < 0 && !put,
        below = destined[cue] > brink[cue] && put == brink[cue] && fad.orbit > 0;
      return above || below;
    }

    function ceaseOperation() {
      return quit.every(function(flag) {
        return flag
      });
    }

    function hindStage() {
      use.turned = use.annul = use.motion = 0;
    }

    function denyRise(jab) {
      jab.preventDefault();
      jab.stopPropagation();
    }

    function elementAnalysis() {
      var item = $();
      if (!object.length) {
        use.crux = true;
        object = vessel;
      }
      object.each(function() {
        if ($.zenith(this)) {
          if (!use.main) {
            if (use.novel) use.main = nib;
            else use.main = baseTag();
            item = item.add(use.main);
          }
        } else item = item.add(this);
      });
      use.target = object = item;
      object.each(function(zest) {
        if ($.zenith(this)) area[zest] = 'hub';
        else area[zest] = 'sub';
      });
      if (use.crux && use.main) vessel = object;
      detectOverflow();
    }

    function baseTag() {
      var origin = gate.scrollTop();
      gate.scrollTop(1);
      if ($('html').scrollTop()) var root = 'html';
      else if ($('body').scrollTop()) root = 'body';
      else root = 'html, body';
      gate.scrollTop(origin);
      return root;
    }

    function detectOverflow() {
      object.each(function(peg) {
        if (area[peg] == 'hub') var teem = $(document).height() - gate.height();
        else teem = this.scrollHeight - $(this).height();
        edge[peg] = Math.round(teem);
      });
    }

    function hasQuiet() {
      var cold = false,
        hike = function() {};
      try {
        var aid = Object.defineProperty({}, 'passive', {
          get: function() {
            cold = true
          }
        });
        nib.addEventListener('test', hike, aid);
        nib.removeEventListener('test', hike, aid);
      } catch (e) {}
      return cold;
    }
  };

  $.zenith = function(sample) {

    var peak = [nib, document, 'HTML', 'BODY'],
      facet;
    if (sample) return peak.indexOf(sample) > -1 || peak.indexOf(sample.tagName) > -1;
    $.each(peak, function(spot, detail) {
      facet = $(detail).data('impulse');
      if (facet) return false;
    });
    return facet;
  };

  $.fn.impulse.default = {

    target: '',
    range: 135,
    leap: 1.35,
    tempo: 500,
    sloth: 1.1,
    curb: 5,
    reset: 85,
    effect: 'easeOutSine',
    keen: true,
    delay: false,
    occur: true,
    fluid: true
  };

  $.fn.demit = function() {

    return this.each(function() {
      if ($.zenith(this)) var habit = $.zenith();
      else habit = $(this).data('impulse');
      if (habit) {
        if (habit.novel) cancelAnimationFrame(habit.motion);
        else habit.target.stop();
        habit.turned = habit.annul = habit.motion = 0;
      }
    });
  };

  $.fn.amend = function(gist) {

    return this.each(function() {
      if ($.zenith(this)) var quirk = $.zenith();
      else quirk = $(this).data('impulse');
      if (quirk) {
        $.each(gist, function(sign, rate) {
          if (sign in quirk) quirk[sign] = rate;
        });
      }
    });
  };

  $.fn.evoke = function(unit) {

    var lot = $.Event('wheel.excite', {
        mien: true
      }),
      bulk;
    return this.each(function() {
      if ($.zenith(this)) {
        if (!bulk) {
          bulk = $.zenith();
          if (bulk) $(bulk.main).trigger(lot, unit);
        }
      } else $(this).trigger(lot, unit);
    });
  };
}(jQuery, window));

(function($) {
  var b = {};
  $.each(['Quad', 'Cubic', 'Quart', 'Quint', 'Expo'], function(i, n) {
    b[n] = function(p) {
      return Math.pow(p, i + 2)
    }
  });
  $.extend(b, {
    Sine: function(p) {
      return 1 - Math.cos(p * Math.PI / 2)
    },
    Circ: function(p) {
      return 1 - Math.sqrt(1 - p * p)
    },
    Elastic: function(p) {
      return p === 0 || p === 1 ? p : -Math.pow(2, 8 * (p - 1)) * Math.sin(((p - 1) * 80 - 7.5) * Math.PI / 15)
    },
    Back: function(p) {
      return p * p * (3 * p - 2)
    },
    Bounce: function(p) {
      var f, h = 4;
      while (p < ((f = Math.pow(2, --h)) - 1) / 11) {}
      return (1 / Math.pow(4, 3 - h) - 7.5625 * Math.pow((f * 3 - 2) / 22 - p, 2))
    }
  });
  $.each(b, function(n, e) {
    $.easing['easeIn' + n] = e;
    $.easing['easeOut' + n] = function(p) {
      return 1 - e(1 - p)
    };
    $.easing['easeInOut' + n] = function(p) {
      return p < 0.5 ? e(p * 2) / 2 : 1 - e(p * -2 + 2) / 2
    }
  })
})(jQuery);
```

```css
.boxes {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 20;
  background-color: transparent;
  top: 0;
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 80%;
}

#box-01 {
  top: 0%;
}

#box-02 {
  top: 80%;
}

#box-03 {
  top: 160%;
}

#set-height {
  display: block;
  height: 20000px;
}

#content-geral {
  background-color: red;
  height: 1000px;
  color: #000;
  text-align: center;
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
}

#content-geral #sub-content-01 {
  position: relative;
}

#set-height #myVideo {
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="set-height">
  <video id="myVideo" tabindex="0" autobuffer="autobuffer" preload="preload">
                    <source type="video/mp4; codecs=&quot;avc1.42E01E, mp4a.40.2&quot;" src="https://www.html5rocks.com/tutorials/video/basics/Chrome_ImF.mp4">
                </video>
  <div class="boxes" id="box-01">
    <h1>box 01</h1>
  </div>
  <div class="boxes" id="box-02">
    <h1>box 02</h1>
  </div>
  <div class="boxes" id="box-03">
    <h1>box 03</h1>
  </div>
</div>
<div id="content-geral">
  <div id="sub-content-01">
    <h1>content-01</h1>
  </div>

</div>
```

O pluggin só funciona quando isto `$(this).impulse();` está dentro da função, mas se estiver corre durante a pagina toda e eu so quero correr o plugin quando estiver com o mouse em cima da div "set-height".

O que eu fiz o plugin Ler foi;

```js
$(window).on('load', function() {

  $("set-height").hover(function() {
    var item = $('.boxes');

    $(this).impulse({
      range: item.height(),
      effect: 'swing',
      delay: true,
    });
  }, function() {
    $(this).impulse({
      range: 500,
      delay: false,
    });
  })
});
```

Tentei fazer como vi [aqui no site do Jquery](https://api.jquery.com/hover/) mas não funcionou, tambem tentei usar os scripts que eles indicam na pagina do pluggin mas não funciona, o plugin so funcionar quando o `$(this).impulse();` está ativo mas eu não quero que ele afete a pagina toda.

Comment: analisando a documentação, uma das opções que você pode passar no objeto passado para o impulse é ```target```, onde você informa o seletor do elemento que deseja animar.

Comment: @ooredroxoo eu reparei nisso e tentei colocar tanto com o "this" tanto com um id e não funcionou.

Comment: pelo que eu entendi o target espera uma string que representa um seletor, nesse caso tenta colocar como o seletor do jquery, por exemplo se for um id colocar assim: ```'#ID'```, se for uma classe ```'.classe'```. O target em si transfere o efeito de scroll de um elemento para o elemento informado no seletor do target.

Comment: @ooredroxoo Sim eu sei mas não funcionou, quando dou scroll com isso assim, a pagina faz o scroll default. Se quiser pode testar o meu codigo dessa forma e pode me dizer se é só comigo que isso funciona assim